# Changing cte for microsoft access

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, common-table-expression

I've tried searching for an answer to this but can't find one.

I have a CTE I use for SQL queries relating to 2 data tables in a database.  The primary key of one table is a foreign key in the other and can appear numerous times in the 2nd table.  I want to do a count of the number of times each foreign key appears in the second table, and list this as a total field in my search results along with details from the first table.  As CTEs don't work in Access I've adjusted this to use a sub select in the join, but it still doesn't like it in access.

Here are the basic parts of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
    [ClientRef] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Forenames] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](40) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CLIE_ClientRef_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientRef] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Policies](
    [PolicyRef] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClientRef] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [POLI_PolicyRef_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PolicyRef] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here's my CTE

```
WITH CliPol (ClientRef, Plans) AS (SELECT ClientRef, COUNT(ClientRef) AS Plans FROM Policies GROUP BY ClientRef)
SELECT Clients.Surname, Clients.Forenames, Clients.Title, CliPol.Plans AS [No. of plans] 
FROM Clients LEFT JOIN CliPol ON Clients.ClientRef = CliPol.ClientRef 
ORDER BY Surname, Forenames;
```

And here's my adjusted query.

```
SELECT Clients.ClientRef, Clients.Surname, Clients.Forenames, Clients.Title , Plans.NoPlans
FROM Clients
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ClientRef, COUNT(ClientRef) AS NoPlans FROM Policies GROUP BY ClientRef) 
    AS Plans ON Plans.ClientRef = Clients.ClientRef
ORDER BY Clients.Surname, Clients.Forenames
```

Unfortunately Access throws error #3131, *"Syntax error in FROM clause"*, when I try to run that query.

Does anybody know how I make this work in Access?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Try changing the order of columns in your join clause (`Clients.ClientRef = Plans.ClientRef`)

Comment: When you say Access doesn't like your subquery approach, does that mean it complains by throwing an error message?

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes, it's telling me there is a syntax error in the FROM clause (Error 3131).

Comment: Why not just create a saved QueryDef object (i.e. via the Query designer) that recreates `CliPol`? Then you can use it like a table in your main query.

Comment: I don't see why Access complains about that `FROM` clause.  Does it accept the subquery as valid? `SELECT plans.* FROM (SELECT ClientRef, COUNT(ClientRef) AS NoPlans FROM Policies GROUP BY ClientRef) AS Plans`

Comment: citizenkong - The SQL is being run via an application using an access database as the back end. The application has a query window that lets you run SQLs to create reports.

Comment: HansUp - actually, just tried that and no it doesn't, so maybe that's the issue then?

Comment: That surely must be significant ... but I can't see why Access has a problem with it.  In Access, are *Clients* and *Policies* ODBC links to SQL Server tables?  If so, delete both links and recreate them.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

One alternate approach would be to use the DCount() domain aggregate function

```sql
SELECT 
    Clients.ClientRef, 
    Clients.Surname, 
    Clients.Forenames, 
    Clients.Title , 
    DCount("ClientRef", "Plans", "ClientRef=" & Clients.ClientRef) AS NoPlans
FROM Clients
ORDER BY Clients.Surname, Clients.Forenames
```